Breaking Ragdoll into pieces
HI to everyone how can i do this that when the ragdoll triggers the gameobject then break the ragdoll into pieces. i want it like this that when the player triggers that gameobject that on which gmaeover scene is loading then first break the ragdoll into pieces i mean the player each joint sperately and then laod the gameover scene now i have already done the ragdoll and loading the scene but only this point is remaining.

Do you need to break the ragdoll into pieces, or would it suffice to hide the ragdoll and spawn separate body part objects at the exact positions and orientations of the ragdoll's parts? Games often use smoke and mirrors tricks like this: what looks like "the same" object might be flipping between different LOD meshes or imposters — what's important is that it appears seamless to the player, even if we're actually doing something quite drastic behind the scenes
